# How can I set the right format to this datetime column with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, format

In a dataframe I have the column "Date and Time" in the format (Year DayoftheYear Houroftheday). For example the first row is (1969 58 0).
I would like to set this column to pandas datetime format. So far, I´ve tried this:

`df['Date and Time']= pd.to_datetime(df["Date and Time"], format = "%YYYY%DDD%H")`

or some other options like:

`df['Date and Time']= pd.to_datetime(df["Date and Time"], format = "%Y%DDD%H")`

`df['Date and Time']= pd.to_datetime(df["Date and Time"], format = "%Y%j%H")`

But any of this options seem to be working. Does someone has any idea on the format I should use to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

`df["Date and Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date and Time"], format="%Y %j %H")`